# Google App Engine: how to find out, which instance is running which instance-class?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created and successfully deployed a NodeJS-app on GoogleAppEngine. I know that they offer several "instance-types" with completely different pricings according to CPU-type, CPU-cores, memory and so on...

One can find the instance classes here in this list: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing

But how do i know, which instance-class is running for my app currently? The dashboard doesnt show me that. "gcloud app instances list" hides this information too. "gcloud app describe" also doesnt provide this information....

How can i find out, which instance is running with which instance class?

### Update

The solution provided by @eater is not available for me as the final "config"-column he had mentioned is not visible in "my" dashboard:

### Update 2

Since this app was configured with "Flexible Environment" the concrete instance type might be not shown here as there is a specific pricing. Apparently this is the answer on my question.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to http://console.cloud.google.com -> select your project in the dropdown on top -> select App Engine on the left hand side menu -> Versions

Select service on the dropdown and then on the list of versions click on the "View" link in the "Config" column. This will show you summary about your version's configuration, including instance type.

For the Flexible environment, there's no instance type as such, instead you can specify resources you want your instance to have, and if you don't specify anything, default values are used. You can see what kind of resources you can specify in this section of documentation
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings
The table also lists default values for resources.

Comment: Unfortunately the "config"-column you have mentioned is not visible to me. I have attached a screenshot of this view. Can you guide me a step ahead pls?

Comment: Did you try to scroll to the right? There are suppose to be two more columns in the table.

Comment: Thanx for pointing out! There was no horizontal scrollbar visible but i increased the window and found the config-column.
It shows "env: flexible" and i think on a non-flexible environment i would here see the concrete instance-class, right?

Comment: Correct, and even for Flexible, you'd see compute resources you've configured for your version, if there's nothing, it means you're using defaults. I've updated my answer to point it out.

Comment: One more thing, you can fetch information about your version using API Explorer, here's a link to the App Engine Admin API https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/app%20engine/appengine/v1/
Go to appengine.apps.services.versions.get to fetch information about your version.

Comment: It works indeed bro.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i can answer by myself:

Since this app was configured with "Flexible Environment" the concrete instance type might be not shown here as there is a specific pricing for "flex"-classes. Apparently this is the answer on my question.